Convoluted crash stack: closure #1 in closure #3
I've been trying to symbolicate a crash report provided by Apple for over an hour. I ended up finding these scripts that actually worked for me: GitHub. This is what I got, but it seems really convoluted, "closure #1 in closure #3 in PhotosModel.getInitialPhotos()" and "partial apply for closure #1 in closure #4 in PhotosModel.getInitialPhotos()." I honestly have no idea where to start. I did a little bit of research, but the threads I found on the Apple forums basically said they had no clue. Any ideas?
Crash stack
0    PhotoSwipe                              closure #1 in closure #3 in PhotosModel.getInitialPhotos() (in PhotoSwipe) + 552
1    PhotoSwipe                              partial apply for closure #1 in closure #4 in PhotosModel.getInitialPhotos() (in PhotoSwipe) (<compiler-generated>:0)
2    PhotoSwipe                              thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (in PhotoSwipe) (<compiler-generated>:0)
3    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1a910113c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
4    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1a9102dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1a91115a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 988
6    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1a91111b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
7    CoreFoundation                          0x1a123d51c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
8    CoreFoundation                          0x1a123a218 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
9    CoreFoundation                          0x1a1239968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
10   GraphicsServices                        0x1e552f4e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
11   UIKitCore                               0x1a36acedc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
12   UIKitCore                               0x1a36ac518 UIApplicationMain + 340
13   SwiftUI                                 0x1a6073860 0x1a5040000 + 16988256
14   SwiftUI                                 0x1a60736a8 0x1a5040000 + 16987816
15   SwiftUI                                 0x1a5c8f9fc 0x1a5040000 + 12909052
16   PhotoSwipe                              main (in PhotoSwipe) (PhotoChoice2App.swift:0)
17   dyld                                    0x1c475ad84 start + 2240

fileprivate func getInitialPhotos() {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        videoOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        totalInitialPhotos = results.count
        
        if results.count > 2 {
            for i in 0..<3 {
                let asset = results.object(at: i)
                let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
                if asset.mediaType == .video {
                    manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions) { (video, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let video = video {
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterVideo(image: video, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let image = image {
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            currentIndex = 3
        } else if results.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<results.count {
                let asset = results.object(at: i)
                let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
                if asset.mediaType == .video {
                    manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions) { (video, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let video = video {
                                self.photoArray.removeLast()
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterVideo(image: video, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let image = image {
                                self.photoArray.removeLast()
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorString = "No photos to display"
            }
        }
        self.photoArray = self.photoArray.reversed()
        print("getAllPhotos() completed")
    }

Above is both the crash stack and the getInitialPhotos() function.

You might use Xcode/Organizer/Crashes, and locate the exact line (ie exact closure).

That's the problem, it's not a submitted crash, but one provided by Apple. I tried going through the organizer, but I couldn't find any way to import a crash.

If it's provided by Apple, it should appear in Xcode/Organizer/Crash (no need to import). Select eh correct build, and check if the crash is there.

Nothing there, they provided three reports, but I'd guess they're all the same problem.
